# Microphone Amplifier

Tags: microphone-technique

Hi

I need a small microphone.I have designed an amplifier circuit that will amplify the audio signal from the microphone and then goes to the computer for recording and analysis.The microphone will be installed on the 26m diameter radio telescope for sound maintenance.After amplification the signal will travel approx. 80m from the dish to the computer.Is it possible that I can get a microphone module to perform this...I need a small microphone not the big conference one...Can I get a small microphone that performs exactly like a big microphone only the difference being the size?

Answer (score 1):

Try an Audio Technica AT803b they can be battery powered and do perform like a big microphone.

http://www.audio-technica.com/cms/wired_mics/ae531e7972b44137/index.html

If this is too big then a DPA 4060 should be suitable, but you will need to rig up a 48 V power supply.

http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=Item&category=128&item=24035